# Azure App Services Reloading site instead of css files

Tags: css, angular, azure

Ok odd one.
I have deployed an example angular application to Azure App Services.
This has worked.. but the styles are failing to load, and on checking

```
https://angularoptimized.azurewebsites.net/styles.7ade3819d0791222.css
```

This fails to load, it is redirecting to the main site.. not failing? I can confirm the file exists. And in case it matters, there are also compressed versions available on the server so wondering if this is being interpreted weirdly??
If checked in a browser, its not identifying the call as a style sheet either. Any ideas?

Comment: When I access the CSS through browser, it shows me an HTML file. Can you check the contents of the file and ensure that it is a valid CSS file.

Comment: Seems the issue is the original file doesn't exist. Just the compressed versions that SHOULD be being served. So the issue is, by default, azure app services isnt loading the compressed versions by default and needs enabling somehow.